# Redirecting HTTP to HTTPS with Google Cloud and Cloudflare

Tags: domain-name-system, https, http, google-cloud-platform, cloudflare

I am hosting a website on Google Cloud, and I have mapped a custom domain name to it, `myurl.com`

When I type `https://www.myurl.com` or `https://myurl.com`, the URL appears correctly in the browser bar.

However, whenever I access the site through HTTP (`http://myurl.com`, `http://www.myurl.com`), the browser bar shows the generic URL `https://something-appspot.com`.

I have tried setting up Cloudflare and activating the option "Always Use HTTPS" and also separately creating a redirect rule (301) from *.myurl to `https://www.myurl.com` - but nothing is working, I keep getting the appspot URL.

I have tried clearing caches and using multiple devices to make sure that the problem is not on the client side.

How could I get all requests, no matter the protocol, to show `https://www.myurl.com`?

Comment: Better remove always use https settings from cloudflare and setup redirection rule on your web server for http to https.

Comment: If using GCP HTTP(s) LB, currently there is no existing feature to redirect HTTP to HTTP(s). However, There is a [feature-request](https://issuetracker.google.com/35904733) in place to support this. As @SunilBhoi mentioned, you can setup redirection rule on the webserver to redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks both, see below. The Cloudflare solution works just fine now - it was just an issue with DNS change propagation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This now works.

The DNS configuration change in my domain name provider had not propagated. If anyone finds this problem, make sure you wait up to 48 hours after making changes to your DNS configuration.

Cloudflare's HTTP to HTTPS auto-rewrites work just fine - the appspot URL appears no longer.